# [frontier_exploration] update explore boundary dynamically

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am using frontier_exploration and rtabmap for my robot autonomous exploration.
Now I can send a goal to explore_server without boundary and start to explore.

I notice that the frontier_exploration will set a **default boundary**
------> the **static map (/map) boundary** provided by rtabmap package.

But the static map provide by rtabmap will grow when the robot go to new place.
Is there any parameter can be adjust, and let the explore costmap boundary will adjust periodically?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241533/%5Bfrontier_exploration%5D-update-explore-boundary-dynamically/) by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The actionlib interface for exploration doesn't really offer that as an option. You can always send a new exploration goal with a larger boundary.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0